# Custom conditional formatting to color multiple column

Tags: google-sheets

I made the formatting so it will flag as red when it detects duplication. My table has 3 column (A,B,C and titled as Id , brand, type respectively). I want to detect if there's duplicate in 'brand' column. It will be colored in red if there's duplication.

I made a formula (as in the attachment) and it works fine, but I want the red color for all the column not only 1 cell (in this case I want all the column A,B,C to be red). If I try changing the 'apply to range' to A2:C1000 , logically this should make col A,B,C to be red. But the result , only col A is red now.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

See below table and the formula:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=countif($B2:$B, $B2) > 1`. See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).